# Is there a way to make a site to display the uptime of a discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot and i have been wanting to add an uptime system to my website example - https://bleed.bot/status, but i dont know how and i cant find any solutions online.

I tried searching on Youtube and google but i did not find anything useful.

Comment: All depends on how site is made. If you are making site in python, you could use IPC to communicate with bot instance and get uptime